# Avoid to include href link in History in React or workaround to achieve inApp navigation

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am working in SPA with React and React Router and I have configured my routes already. I have in the "HomePage" an icon to open the Menu, but when the user navigates into some option, a "backArrow" icon is used to navigate to the previous page with the:

```
<IconButton 
onClick={ () => navigate( -1 ) }
>
<ArrowBack />
</IconButton >
```

So far so good. My issue is that I have one resource in the app where the user navigates to a folder in /public and then comes back to the app. I don't want the user to visit that resource clicking the ArrowBack, but only when clicking the specific button. Visiting that resource is done with:

```
<Button>
  <Link href={ LinkToPublicResource } >GO</Link>
</Button>
```

Notice that the "Link" is not the one from React Router but from Material UI in order to format the style of the link.

How could I avoid that link to be included in History so the user does not comes back to it clicking in the BackArrow? Is it possible some workaround to ignore visits to this resource for React Router?

My issue is that the when the user is navigating through the menu a usual navigation would be:

```
1) / --> 2) /posts --> 3) /posts/post:id --> 4) ExternalResource
```

After visiting the ExternalResource, the user comes back to "3) post:id" where the BackArrow icon is found, and clicking it, which triggers the navigate(-1) goes again to the ExternalResource but I would like the user to go back to /posts.

I hope I have explained a little better the issue. Thanks.

Comment: Is `LinkToPublicResource` an external (*to the app*) URL path? Can you clarify what/where/how any back button in the UI is related to this link? See [mcve].

Comment: It is an external link as it is a small HTML/JS resource that is not included in the React application so the user goes out from the SPA clicking the "LinkToPublicResource" and then goes back to the application when done using it. The issue is that when the user has visited the resource and comes back, by clicking the BackArrow goes back to that link because it is in the History.

Comment: Ok, and can you clarify the what/where/how that back button is related to the link? What the issue is?

Comment: Oh, didn't see your edit. How is the user navigating back to your app? If it's a back navigation then clicking the back button can only navigate further back, it won't navigate forward.

Comment: I see. Use redirects (REPLACE) instead of navigations (PUSH) from step (3) on so any back navigations take you back to (2).